# App crash just with store app 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios7

I 've got an iOS-app which is available in Appstore. Today I test the app and it crashes on my iPhone4 (iOS7), when the app tries to open an error dialog. On iPhone5s no problems.

When I install the app from XCode it works... XCode/Appstore are the same version.
I read the console in XCode to figure out why the app crashs. I got this error:

> following error: : *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to
>   present a nil modal view controller on target

What I am doing wrong? 
When I call my errordialog I do this:

```
self.showAlert("Error.", message: "Wrong credentials.", owner: self);
```

The error method:

```
func showAlert(title:NSString, message:NSString,owner:UIViewController) {
    if let gotModernAlert: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil));
        owner.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
    else {
        let alertView = UIAlertView(title: title, message: message, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "OK");
        alertView.alertViewStyle = .Default;
        alertView.show();
    }
}
```

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to check class

```
+ (BOOL) checkIfClassExists:(NSString *)className {
id c = objc_getClass([className cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
if (c != nil) {
    return YES;
} else {
    return NO;
}
```

}

& in swift use as

```
if ObjCFix.checkIfClassExists("UIAlertController") {
//iOS 8 code here
} else {
//iOS 7 code here
```

}

Comment: I have implemented a check for version. And it works, when I am not using the app from store. Just when I use it from store. I don't think this check will help me, or?

Comment: try at least once may it helps u.I think the condition of checking is wrong .

Comment: But itss really hard to test... The app just crashes, when I use the version from store. Loaded from XCode everything works perfect...